# Visual c++ identifier was not declared

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I came across some meaningless errors in when I was told that the identifier was not declared

```
    POINT positionCursor;
    HWND handle;
    LPWSTR title;
    int bufsize;


    mousePosition->Text=Cursor->Position.ToString();
    positionCursor.x = Cursor->Position.X;
    positionCursor.y = Cursor->Position.Y;

    handle = WindowFromPhysicalPoint(positionCursor);

    bufsize = GetWindowTextLength(handle) + 1;
    title = new WCHAR[bufsize];

    GetWindowText(handle, title, bufsize);
    std::wstring temp = title;
    System::String ^str3 = Convert::ToString(temp.c_str());

    windowText->Text= str3;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be regarding `mousePosition`, which wasn't declared in the code you provided? Also, what is `windowText`? Seems like we're missing some more code...

Comment: is a label in main form